# What is the justification for Lagrange-multipliers in the calculus of variations with integral constraints?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

Suppose that $D$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, that $F,G \in \mathcal{C}^2(D)$, and that $L$, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are given real constants with $a<b$

The problem is, to find, amongst all $y \in \mathcal{C}^2([a, b])$ for which

$$
y(a)= c,
$$

$$
 y(b)= d, 
$$

$$
(x, y(x),y'(x)) \in D \quad \forall x ∈ [a, b], \quad \text{and} 
$$

$$
\int_{a}^b G(x, y(x), y'(x)) dx = L,
$$

holds, the function $y$, which gives an extreme value (a maximum or a minimum) to the integral

$$ I(y) := \int_{a}^b F(x, y(x), y'(x)) dx.$$

This a the generic case of a variational optimization problem with integral constraints.

On several spots in the literature, I have seen people approach this problem (without further explanation!) using so-called ***Lagrange multipliers***.

I understand the role and mechanism of Lagrange multipliers when optimizing finite-dimensional functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. However, I do not understand how one can generalize this technique to solve the above problem.

Can someone illustrate the use of Lagrange multipliers for the solution of the above integral-constraint problem and give **rigorous** mathematical arguments for why it works?

Comment: I guess a proper discussion of this situation would have to start of by formulating a version of the Lagrange Multiplier theorem which is valid in infinite dimensions. This can be found in Abraham Marsden Ratiu's book on manifolds in Supplement 3.5A. (I haven't gone through the details myself so I can't really explain it to you)